# Knockout foreach bound to value in inputfield

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to autogenerate a number of labels on the bottom of my page based on what someone fills in in an inputfield.

So when someone fills in "2", I want 2 labels to pop up, preferable when he typed it without leaving the inputfield or anything.

This is what I have:

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="if_aantalMensen">
            Hoeveel extra mensen wil je inschrijven?
      </label>
      <div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="if_aantalMensen" name="if_aantalMensen" 
                 data-bind="textInput: aantalMensen">
      </div>
</div>
<div data-bind="foreach: aantalMensenArray" class="form-group">
      <label><span data-bind="text: $index"></span></label>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var vm = {
aantalMensen: ko.observable(0),
aantalMensenArray: ko.computed(function() {
    var fields = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < self.selectedNumberOfFields(); i++) {
        fields.push(new Parameter());
    }
    return fields;
})}
```

It works if I just make "`aantalMensenArray`" into an `observableArray` that already has values in it. However, I can't get it to change the amount of labels shown.

Comment: can you make fiddle or show complete view model code?

Comment: is this what you looking for `whimsy` check this http://jsfiddle.net/A7XY3/28/ . hope it helps let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'

```
"http://jsfiddle.net/dpa6zk9j/"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I need, except that I'm gonna need to reset the fields every time the value changes.